# How can a process find the pids of processes it communicates with over a pipe?

Tags: unix, process, ipc, pipe, pid

Let's say I have the following pipeline:

```
$ generator_process | filter_process | storage_process
```

Is it possible for `filter_process` to find out the pid of `generator_process` and `storage_process`? If so, how? If not, why?

More generally, how can a process find the pids of processes it communicates with over a pipe?

I'm looking for a portable (POSIX) way to do this, but if it requires some platform-specific trickery, a Linux solution is what I'm looking for. I guess an answer in C would give most detail but if it involves the shell, I'm looking for a bash solution.

Please assume that I can change `filter_process` but `generator_process` and `storage_process` are programs that I have no possibility or desire to alter (they could be standard Unix tools that I don't want to fiddle with). Also, wrapping them in scripts that write their pids to disk is not the solution I'm after.

Comment: Related or almost duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/244413/how-do-you-determine-the-actual-command-that-is-piping-into-you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that one end of a pipe might be open in more than one process simultaneously (through `fork()` or `sendmsg` file-descriptor transmission), so you might not get just one answer.

In Linux, you can examine `/proc/<pid>/fd` to see what `fds` it has open (you need to be `root`, or the same uid as the target process). I just ran `grep a | grep b` and got the following output:

```
/proc/10442/fd:
total 0
dr-x------ 2 nneonneo nneonneo  0 Sep 20 02:19 .
dr-xr-xr-x 7 nneonneo nneonneo  0 Sep 20 02:19 ..
lrwx------ 1 nneonneo nneonneo 64 Sep 20 02:19 0 -> /dev/pts/5
l-wx------ 1 nneonneo nneonneo 64 Sep 20 02:19 1 -> pipe:[100815116]
lrwx------ 1 nneonneo nneonneo 64 Sep 20 02:19 2 -> /dev/pts/5

/proc/10443/fd:
total 0
dr-x------ 2 nneonneo nneonneo  0 Sep 20 02:19 .
dr-xr-xr-x 7 nneonneo nneonneo  0 Sep 20 02:19 ..
lr-x------ 1 nneonneo nneonneo 64 Sep 20 02:19 0 -> pipe:[100815116]
lrwx------ 1 nneonneo nneonneo 64 Sep 20 02:19 1 -> /dev/pts/5
lrwx------ 1 nneonneo nneonneo 64 Sep 20 02:19 2 -> /dev/pts/5
```

So it follows that by using `readlink` on your own process's fd, followed by `readlink` on other process fds you own, you can figure out who is on the other side of the pipe.

Madly hackish way to find out (from within a Bash script) which pids and fds are connected to a particular pipe:

```
get_fd_target() {
    pid=$1
    fd=$2
    readlink /proc/$pid/fd/$fd
}

find_fd_target() {
    target=$1
    for i in /proc/*/fd/*; do
        if [ "`readlink $i`" == "$target" ]; then
            echo $i
        fi
    done
}
```

Then, if you want to find out what fds on the system are connected to your script's stdin:

```
find_fd_target `get_fd_target $$ 0`
```

Comment: This is pretty much the solution, for Linux at least. With suitable extensions, I can distinguish between reader and writer processes. Thanks!